# How to run something after all the @Before's have happened?

Tags: junit

We're using @Before's all along the hierarchy to get some test data inserted into the database before tests execute.  I want to commit all that data to the database just before the @Test starts running.

One way to do this would be to commit the data as the last step in this test class' @Before method.  But we have hundreds of such classes, and don't want to go in and modify all of those.

I've played with ExternalResource @Rule and TestWatcher @Rule...but they don't afford a way to hook in after all the @Before's have happened.

I'm thinking I need to look at building a custom TestRunner to do this.

Is that the right track?

Comment: What about just having a utility method that you call as the first line of each test? The disadvantage of writing your own running is that you will be able to use the other runners (Spring, Theories, etc).

Comment: Well that would work. But it's pretty close to the alternate I already mentioned. It's important to get this right, so I'm hoping for a nifty trick that'll let me get in there.  

I can't be the first person to need this, right?

Comment: My best bet is to “go in and modify all of those” using sed or some script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for, seems inconsistent to me. Settind some data and committing them are very close operations and shouldn't belong to different places. On the contrary, I would rather put them into one function and call it with actual parameters set to values you want to insert. Or use SQL strings as actual parameters.  And call this finction from @Before

If you are insisting, there is no problem to do it. Create descendant classes for your Junit classes:

```
package ...;
import org.junit.Before;
public class NewAndBetterYourTest1 extends YourTest1 {
    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp(); // this is where you are setting everything.
        makeCommits();
    }
}
```

Only don't forget to launch these new tests

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do quite what you are asking without a custom Runner, you could ensure that all of the data created in the `@Before` methods is committed with a Rule:

```
public class LocalDatabase extends ExternalResource {
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Override
  protected void before() {
    dataSource = createLocalDatabase();
  }

  @Override
  protected void after() {
    try {
      destoyLocalDatabase(dataSource);
    } finally {
      dataSource = null;
    }
  }

  public void run(Callback callback) {
    if (dataSource == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No DataSource");
    }
    Collection con = null;
    try {
      con = ds.getConnection(DB_USERNAME, PASSWORD);
      callback.execute(con);
      con.commit();
    } finally {
      if (con != null) con.close();
    }
  }
```

You can have this as a Rule in your base class:

```
public DatabaseTest {
  @Rule
  public LocalDatabase final localDatabase = new LocalDatabase();
}
```

And could could use it in a `@Before` method in any subclass

```
public UserDaoTest extends DatabaseTest {

  @Before
  public void populateInitialData() {
    localDatabase.run(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void execute(Connection con) {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
  ...
}
```